# Test multipart PUT request with json data using mockMvc

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, spring-test, mockmvc

I am trying to unit test a put request which takes a file and some json data as request body. following is the method i am trying to test:

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/{id}",
    method = RequestMethod.PUT,
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
public ResponseEntity<UpdateT1Output> update(@PathVariable String id, @ModelAttribute @Valid UpdateT1Input t1) {
    // implementation here
}
```

UpdateT1Input.java

```
public class UpdateT1Input {

    private char[] ca;

    private byte[] file;
    public void setFile(MultipartFile mpfile) {
        try {
            file = mpfile.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private List<Double> flpa;

    private List<Double> fpa;

    @NotNull(message = "id Should not be null")
    private Long id;

    private String str;

    private Long versiono;
}
```

test setup

```
        @Test
    public void UpdateT1_T1Exists_ReturnStatusOk() throws Exception {
        // create entity obj with default values
        T1Entity entity = createUpdateEntity();
        entity.setVersiono(0L);

        UpdateT1Input t1Input = new UpdateT1Input();
        t1Input.setId(entity.getId());
        t1Input.setFlpa(entity.getFlpa());
        t1Input.setStr(entity.getStr());

        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .writer()
            .withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = ow.writeValueAsString(t1Input);
  
        MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder =
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/t1/" + entity.getId());
        builder.with(request -> {
            request.setMethod("PUT");
            return request;
        });
        mvc.perform(builder
                .file("file", "ABC".getBytes("UTF-8"))
                .content(json)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

but in controller only id and file fields are set in input dto all other fields are null. i am using @ModelAttribute to avoid dividing request into file and data parts. so is there a way that to get all the fields in single object?